# What does the error it is giving me mean? sql recursive

Tags: sql, recursive-datastructures

I'm trying to build a table of costars (name1, name2) of names of actors who have acted in the same movie.

For this I make use of three tables: titles(id, titles), names(id, names) and acted(name_id, title_id) and for this I built this code based on what I have seen in classes. I am a newbie, I am learning to work with sql.

```
WITH RECURSIVE costars(actor1, actor2) AS (
    SELECT title_id, name_id, names.name
    FROM acted
    JOIN names ON acted.name_id = names.id
    --ORDER BY title_id ASC
    union
    SELECT costars.actor1, acted.actor2
    FROM costars
    JOIN acted ON costars.actor2 = acted.name_id
) 
SELECT * 
FROM costars

ERROR:  column acted.actor2 does not exist
LINE 8:  SELECT costars.actor1, acted.actor2
                                ^
Estado SQL: 42703
Caracter: 192
```

Comment: Does the table `acted` have a column named `actor2`?

Comment: For starters, you define your cte as having two columns, but you select 3.

Comment: @TheImpaler I think the error couldn't be clearer in that respect

Comment: On a more general note, if you are just trying to create pairs of actors, you don’t need a recursive query

Comment: actor 1 and actor are the data that I must add in the costars table

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do the code without recursion:

```
SELECT DISTINCT na1.name AS actor_1, na2.name AS actor_2
FROM acted A1, acted A2, names na1, names na2
WHERE A1.title_id = A2.title_id
AND A1.name_id = na1.id
AND A2.name_id = na2.id
AND na1.name <> na2.name
ORDER BY na1.name, na2.name;
```